# LAMP, XAMPP for production

Tags: linux, xampp, lamp

Every LAMP or XAMPP writeup or tutorial I see says "Not for production use", so what do I use for production?

Answer (score 8):

you use apache, php and mysql installed as they should be for production. xampp is all those things in one package with basically no set up security .. root passwords are empty .. users are well known .. but the components are the same as the ones you would use if you downloaded them each ..

Answer (score 4):

The [XAMPP philosophy](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html#300) says:

> The philosophy behind XAMPP is to build an easy to install distribution for developers to get into the world of Apache. To make it convenient for developers XAMPP is configured with all features turned on.
>
> The default configuration is not good from a securtiy point of view and it's not secure enough for a production environment - please don't use XAMPP in such environment.

So it’s primarily designated as a development environment and not as a production environment.

Comment: XAMPP gives you ways to lock down the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Given the right installation options, you can use them as a starting point for a production server. But there are some holes to fill in, mainly wrt security. The disclaimers you refer to are (wisely) to make sure you are wary and suspicious of what you start with (and also make sure no one can claim they supplied you with something dangerous without letting you know, so don't blame them if Bad Things happen.)

It's like selling you a car without seatbelts.

But what you learn, and the solutions you develop, are generally fully compatible with a "real" server.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP installation is easy as compared to LAMP. If you are on development server it makes no difference, but if you are on production server than it is good to do from basic instead of relying on 3rd party and you will get exact services you want on your production server, no extra services which can lower down your production server performance.

And try to keep same setup on development and production server, it will make sure that if application is running on development server will also run on production without doing any extra settings.

Answer (score -1):

For production you've make your own configuration, it depends on  visitors count, RAM installed on  your server, scripts you're using. F.E. You need only 5 PHP extensions for Wordpress, but if you're using Woocommerce you need more PHP memory, for multiple sites you've use VirtualHosts, and if you have not domains registered also  user UserDir modules. 
All I've said is only examples, you must know your script requirements, install  everything is not good idea.